# how to dynamically create tables based on the inputs from the user?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This is my stored procedure to compare 2 tables:

I am dynamically receiving the table name and the columns to compare

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE SP_TBL_COMPARE_TEST(r_cursor OUT sys_refcursor,
SRC_TBL_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
TGT_TBL_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
SRC_COLS     IN VARCHAR2,
TGT_COLS     IN VARCHAR2) IS   CNT1     NUMBER(5);  CNT2     NUMBER(5); CNT3     NUMBER(5);
SQL_TEXT VARCHAR(1000);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' ||SRC_TBL_NAME INTO CNT1;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' ||TGT_TBL_NAME INTO CNT2;
  dbms_output.put_line('counted: ' || cnt1);
  dbms_output.put_line('counted: ' || cnt2);
  IF CNT1 != CNT2 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('count is not maching');
  ELSE
    SQL_TEXT := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ((SELECT * FROM '|| SRC_TBL_NAME ||' MINUS SELECT * FROM '|| TGT_TBL_NAME || ') UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM '|| TGT_TBL_NAME|| ' MINUS  SELECT * FROM '|| SRC_TBL_NAME || '))';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_TEXT INTO CNT3;
    dbms_output.put_line(SQL_TEXT);
    dbms_output.put_line('No of non matching rows: ' || cnt3);
OPEN R_CURSOR FOR '(SELECT '|| SRC_COLS ||' FROM '|| SRC_TBL_NAME ||' MINUS SELECT '|| TGT_COLS ||' FROM '|| TGT_TBL_NAME || ') UNION  (SELECT '|| TGT_COLS ||' FROM '|| TGT_TBL_NAME|| ' MINUS  SELECT '|| SRC_COLS ||' FROM '|| SRC_TBL_NAME || ') ';
END IF;
END;
```

I'll have to dynamically create table based on the cols entered by the user and insert the non matching records between source and target. can you help on how to do it?

the column values might changes everytime the user runs the proc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create table dynamically using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement.

Like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE %YOUR_TABLE% AS ' || '%YOUR_QUERY_FOR_NON_MATCHING_ROWS%';
```